# irregular behavior ajax timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, request

In a web project I am making an ajax request with jquery, but I need to increase the timeout to close to 10 minutes. The great thing is that it only waits 2 minutes and fails. Does Jquery have a limit to wait for the answers of your requests?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your ajax request is not timing out, the *server* is rejecting the request.  There will be a timeout on the *server* configuration, so will depend on what server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. A value of 0 means there will be no timeout. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

From the image, it appears you are not explicitly setting a timeout, meaning it is defaulting to 0 and should have an "infinite" timeout. So if it is still timing out, it could be because of many reasons. A couple are:

1. The browser is closing the connection. You may be able to fix this by passing the `keep-alive` header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive
2. The server is closing the connection. This will depend on the server config (apache, nginx, tomcat, etc.).

If you need a connection open for ten minutes, AJAX isn't really the right technology to use. Check out WebSockets with something like [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/).

Comment: Would this not be setting the timeout? `$.ajax({... timeout: 600000 })`

Comment: Oh nevermind, I didn't see that part. Need more coffee! Yes, that is setting a timeout -- but clearly either the browser or the server is closing the connection early. Try the HTTP header for keep-alive and if that doesn't work, check your server settings for maximum http connection time, and if none of that works, look at using WebSockets.

Comment: And if the request might take *ten minutes,* maybe a different protocol would be better anyway:  the AJAX request submits a "job" and returns a "job-ID" nonce.  Other calls let you query the ongoing status of the "job" and eventually to retrieve its output.  (Of course there are plenty of existing workflow management systems that do this sort of thing.)